# Scroll view not scrolling once expanded image view dismisses

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

After adding code that when tapped, my image view expands to be full screen. I am unable to scroll in my scroll view once the view is dismissed with a UITapGestureRecognizer.

Here is the code to present and dismiss the image view (works well):

```
 @IBAction func imageTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let imageView = sender.view as! UIImageView
        let newImageView = UIImageView(image: imageView.image)
        newImageView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        newImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.8)
        newImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        newImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector(dismissFullscreenImage))
        let swipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissFullscreenImage))
        newImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        newImageView.addGestureRecognizer(swipe)
        self.view.addSubview(newImageView)
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
    }

    @objc func dismissFullscreenImage(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer {
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
        sender.view?.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

This is how I set the content size of my scroll view if needed (this worked fine before adding the above code) :

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

        let ogSize = eventMainView.frame.size

        eventMainScrollView.contentSize = changeCG(theview: ogSize)
    }
```

Comment: What does your changeCG do?

Comment: it just sets the correct scroll size I want for the VC, it works fine @PavelKozlov